# tcm is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, command-line, installation, path, tableau

I am trying to install Tableau Server on my Windows machine. I downloaded the first Tabcmd file from here: https://www.tableau.com/support/releases/server/2021.2.1#esdalt

and ran the setup on my computer. Now, as mentioned here: https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/setup.htm

I tried running this command

```
TableauServerTabcmd-64bit-2021-2-1.exe /silent ACCEPTEULA=1
```

but I get an error that:

```
'TableauServerTabcmd-64bit-2021-2-1.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I get the same error when I just check `tsm` on the cmd. I also tried adding the following path in system variables:

```
C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\2021.2\extras\Command Line Utility
```

but I still get the same error. How can I install Tableau Server successfully?

Comment: were you in the correct location when you executed that command? you need to be in the directory where `TableauServerTabcmd-64bit-2021-2-1.exe` is, or call it with it's full name like `C:\path\to\file\TableauServerTabcmd-64bit-2021-2-1.exe` this is probably the installation exe, I doubt it's present in the `Command Line Utility` folder. That's why adding it to path didn't bring you any luck

Comment: Yup, I am in the correct folder @SimonS

Comment: then the exe has a different name, or you're not in the correct folder after all. There is no way that `cmd.exe` does not find an exe in the current location. This is not a problem with the application you want to install. Try it by specifying the whole path to the exe, maybe that helps (shift right click the exe and copy the path to file, then you're sure you have no typos)

Comment: Ah I am actually using Parallels to run Windows on a Macbook. Even though I am In the right (Downloads) folder, it's not working. @SimonS